# Setting multiple models on a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm playing around with angularjs and would like to make a dual list box- the kind where the list on the left is everything, and the list on the right contains items 'pushed' from one list to the other.  Arrows to do the pushing of items back and forth.

I can do this pretty easily just in straight html and using angularjs, but I was looking into how I could make it reusable, something like this:
`<dual-list-box all-items='currentController.allItems' selected-items='currentController.selectedItems' />`

Where I can sort of pass in the two lists.. so no matter the controller or list names I can use my dual list box control.

Is this possible?  How?  I'm thinking the directive might work, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

And I'm not sure I'm thinking about this quite the right way....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directive should certainly work here.  Something like:

```
module.directive('dualListBox', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { // set up isolated scope, bind to parent scope's properties (declared in view)
            allItems: '=',
            selectedItems: '='
        },
        template: 'HTML template, can bind to allItems and selectedItems in isolated scope',
        link: (scope, elm, attr) {
            // use to scope.allItems & scope.selectedItems here
        }
    }
});
```

That's the idea.  You might want to refer to the [documentation for directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) during implementation.

Comment: That syntax creates something called "isolated scope", which contains properties bound with properties of the parent scope as declared in the views, allowing you to declare the HTML exactly as what you asked for in the question.  Its syntax is a bit convoluted at first (with that equal sign, I know), you should definitely read up the link I sent.

Comment: Oh- maybe this is a separate question- is it possible to pass in `allItems` but as ngOptions?  Like this: `<dual-listbox allItems="item.FirstName for person in people | orderBy:'FirstName'"  />`

Comment: Good question, but that wouldn't work. The syntax 'in' isn't part of AngularJS expression, it's s/t only supported by ngRepeat. I think you should just create a custom filter to get out the first name, changing the whole expression to something like 'people | orderBy:'FirstName' | select:'FirstName' where `select` is the custom filter to build.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, this keeps the method for moving between the two inside the directives scope. However, instead of having arrows (wasn't sure what you meant, i.e. only move the bottom element, or an arrow for each, or what), you just click an element to shift it over.

```
myApp.directive('duallist', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        data1: '=',
        data2: '='          
    },
    template: '<div><ul class="list"><li ng-repeat="datum in data1" ng-click="move(datum, data1)">{{datum}}</li></ul> <ul class="list"><li ng-repeat="datum in data2" ng-click="move(datum, data2)">{{datum}}</li></ul></div>',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
        scope.move = function(datum, dataset) {
            if (dataset == scope.data1) {
            scope.data2.push(datum);
            dataset.splice(dataset.indexOf(datum), 1);                  
            }
            else{
            scope.data1.push(datum);
            dataset.splice(dataset.indexOf(datum), 1);    
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

});

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/

Comment: Bugger, I forgot to save it! I'll get you a working version in an hour or so if you still need it?